# Cancel C# 4.5 TcpClient ReadAsync by timeout

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.5, tcpclient

What would be the proper way to cancel TcpClient ReadAsync operation by timeout and catch this timeout event in .NET 4.5?

TcpClient.ReadTimeout seems to be applied to the sync Read only.

UPDATE:
Tried to apply the approach described here [Cancelling an Asynchronous Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418.aspx)

```
var buffer = new byte[4096];
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
int amountRead = await tcpClientStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 4096, cts.Token);
```

but it never cancels itself by the given timeout. Is anything wrong?

Comment: I dont see `ReadAsync` on `TcpClient`.

Comment: Sorry, it's NetworkStream.ReadAsync

Answer (score 12):

so I know that was from a long time 
but google still drive me here 
and I saw there is none marked as answer

for me, I solve like that 
I make an extension to add a method ReadAsync that takes extra timeout

```
public static async Task<int> ReadAsync(this NetworkStream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, int TimeOut)
{
    var ReciveCount = 0;
    var receiveTask = Task.Run(async () => { ReciveCount = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count); });
    var isReceived = await Task.WhenAny(receiveTask, Task.Delay(TimeOut)) == receiveTask;
    if (!isReceived) return -1;
    return ReciveCount;
}
```

so if it returned -1 that mean the read timed out

Comment: Won't that read potentially complete causing inconsistent data from the socket?

Comment: I believe it's not guaranteed that the value of ReciveCount would be updated as it's neither volatile nor atomic.  Or task completion and task await operation create a memory barrier?

Comment: as this thread suggests https://stackoverflow.com/q/41928139/716769 it could really happen that variable won't be changed in caller thread

Comment: how to call it ?

Comment: how to call it ?

Answer (score 6):

Edit: the following gist is a workaround I did for this.
https://gist.github.com/svet93/fb96d8fd12bfc9f9f3a8f0267dfbaf68

Original:

I really liked the answer from [Khalid Omar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41193744/5149679) and did my own version of it which I thought was worth sharing:

```
public static class TcpStreamExtension
{
    public static async Task<int> ReadAsyncWithTimeout(this NetworkStream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (stream.CanRead)
        {

            Task<int> readTask = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count);
            Task delayTask = Task.Delay(stream.ReadTimeout);
            Task task = await Task.WhenAny(readTask, delayTask);

            if (task == readTask)
                    return await readTask;

        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It is more or less the same thing except slightly differently formatted in a way that is more readable (to me), and more importantly it does not use `Task.Run` I wasn't sure why it was used in his example.

Edit:

The above may seem good in a first glance but I found out it causes some problems. The readAsync call seems to leak if no data comes in, and in my case it seems that it reads a later write and the data is essentially returned within a place in memory no longer used.

Answer (score 3):

Passing a `CancellationToken` to `ReadAsync()` doesn't add much value because it checks the status of the token **only before** [it starts reading](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Stream.cs,448):

```cs
// If cancellation was requested, bail early with an already completed task.
// Otherwise, return a task that represents the Begin/End methods.
return cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested
            ? Task.FromCanceled<int>(cancellationToken)
            : BeginEndReadAsync(buffer, offset, count);
```

You can quite easily add a timout mechanism yourself by waiting for either the `ReadAsync()` or the timout task to complete like this:

```cs
byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

var readTask = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
await Task.WhenAny(readTask, timeoutTask);
if (!readTask.IsCompleted)
{
    throw new TimeoutException($"Connection timed out after {timeout}");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: OK, that locks up a thread. But for many applications, this is still a simple solution, I think.

OK, so this is an old thread, but I thought I'd share my own solution, as it seems much more simple.

Instead of using e.g.

```
int length = await stream.Read(buffer, 0, 2, cancellationToken);
```

simply use

```
int length = 0;
await Task.Run(() => { length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 2); });
```

and this respects stream.ReadTimeout just fine.

Comment: Running synchronous code will sleep your threads