# Reading from COM port with BaseStream.BeginRead and getting a substring

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

Im trying to read from a com port, this is my code

```
   public string HouseState()
    {
        string state = string.Empty;
     if (!Variables.portBusy)
            {
                // Begin communications
                var blockLimit = 13;
                openSerial();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[blockLimit];
                Action kickoffRead = null;

                kickoffRead = delegate
                {
                    serialPort.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, delegate (IAsyncResult ar)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int actualLength = serialPort.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
                            byte[] received = new byte[actualLength];
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, received, 0, actualLength);
                            state += System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received);
                            //MessageBox.Show(state);
                        }
                        catch (IOException exc)
                        {
                            //handleAppSerialError(exc);
                        }
                        if (state.Count() <= 13)
                            kickoffRead();
                    }, null);
                };
                kickoffRead();
            }
        MessageBox.Show(state);
        var index = state.IndexOf("R");
        var command = string.Empty;
        if (index >= 0)
            command = state.Substring(index, 13);


        return command;
    }
```

What im trying to get is a string that starts with R and has 13 characters. Because sometimes the port sends half the string i do this: **if (state.Count() <= 13)**

But while inside BaseStream the state string gets what i want, when i try to read the string of state, it appears empty. The MessageBox shows an empty string.

why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BeginRead` method of `SerialPort.BaseStream` is asynchronous so by the moment you're getting to `MessageBox.Show(state);` the actual read may have not completed yet and `state` is still empty. You need to wait until all necessary data is read:

```
// .....................
var readComplete = new ManualResetEvent(false);
kickoffRead = delegate
{
    serialPort.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, delegate (IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // ...................
        if (state.Count() <= 13)
            kickoffRead();
        else
            readComplete.Set();
    }, null);
};
kickoffRead();
readComplete.WaitOne();
// ......................
```

Having said that `BeginRead`/`EndRead` based async reading is superseded by `ReadAsync` one. And based on your original snippet even synchronous read is acceptable in your case. You may find examples for both in the answers to this question: [C# Async Serial Port Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041378/c-sharp-async-serial-port-read)

Comment: you rock bro, i didnt know it was async, why it doens require async command?
Also i didnt know about this ManualResetEvent, thanks

Comment: The `async` keyword is supposed to be used with [new async model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx) methods. Being of the old async model implementation, `BeginRead` is not aware of tasks and `async`/`await`.