# Serial port continuous data reading

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, communication

I've made and application using WPF and I have to implement serial communication.
Bellow i have the DataReceived function.

The main problem is that the function triggers only sometimes, does anybody have a better solution to DataReceived trigger in WPF?

Below is the connection Connection to ComPort

```
  public static void connnect(string recPort)
        {
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer MyTimer = null;
            bool error = false;
                String serialpname = recPort;
                ComPort = new SerialPort();
                if (ComPort.IsOpen == false)
                {
                ComPort.PortName = serialpname;
                ComPort.BaudRate = 38400;  
                ComPort.Parity = Parity.None; 
                ComPort.DataBits = 8;
                ComPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                ComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnSerialDataReceived);
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
                dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
                dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
                try
                {
                    if (ComPort.IsOpen == false)
                    {
                        //Open Port
                        ComPort.Open();
                        dispatcherTimer.Start();
                    }
                }              
                catch (System.IO.IOException) { error = true; }              
            }
        }
```

Below is the timer that interogates the port

```
  private static void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ComPort.Write(eot + "11" + STX + "2170" + ENQ); // get pos 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

The datareceived event

```
public static void OnSerialDataReceived(object sender,
        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
{           
    bool isString = true;
    try
    {
      Thread.Sleep(100);// this solves the problem
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[ComPort.ReadBufferSize];

        int readLen = ComPort.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);

        string readStr = string.Empty;
        if (isString)
        {
            readStr = Encoding.Default.GetString(readBuffer, 0, readLen);
            if(readStr.Length > 10)
            {
                if (readStr.StartsWith("\u0002"))
                {
                    Position = (Mid(readStr, 2, 5));
                    Messenger.Default.Send("NewPos");
                }
                else
                {
                    Position = (Mid(readStr, 31, 4));
                    Messenger.Default.Send("NewPos");
                }
              }
        }
        else
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < readLen; i++)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(readBuffer[i].ToString("X2") + " ");
            }
            readStr = stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: As with most event-based I/O, you probably should get into the habbit of coding what is immediately required and leave the rest for another thread to process.  Otherwise if you spend too much time doing compute or other forms of I/O (say `Messenger.Default.Send`) and it takes too long, you could run into _buffer overrun errors_ whereby data is lost.  The sender might be running into timeouts too if you take too long.  So you could for example, read the COM data and store it and quickly return from the callback

Comment: ...or actually use `async` I/O.  Even though the `ComPort` class has no explicit `async` support, the port's `BaseStream` does. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32436104/585968.  This approach is much nicer than fiddling about with queues :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i've removed the other I/O and the other I/O forms but the problem with the DataReceived is persisting. From what i have seen, if I put a breakpoint in the function it works as it should.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you setup `ComPort`? Particularly, baud, parity, flow control etc.  Also what type of device are you talking to?

Comment: Yes, for sure:
                    ComPort.PortName = serialpname;
                    ComPort.BaudRate = 38400;   
                    ComPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                    ComPort.DataBits = 8;
                    ComPort.StopBits = StopBits.One; 
                    ComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnSerialDataReceived);
            
It's a controller board for servo motors and pneumatic controls, from which I have to read the position of the motors and different other states.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60025155/edit) your question to include that info

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, i have added a Thread.Sleep(100); in the datareceived function. The buffer was not filled with the incoming data and seems that was the cause.
Thank you.