# Thread safety on async/await with memory caching

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, caching, asynchronous

I was having a look at the section on memory barriers as described in http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx
and attempted to make an async/await version of the example provided under 'Do We Really Need Locks and Barriers?':

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestAsync();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static async void TestAsync()
    {
        bool complete = false;
        Func<Task> testFunc = async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            bool toggle = false;
            while (!complete) toggle = !toggle;
        };

        var task = testFunc();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        complete = true;
        await task;
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

When run under release mode without debugging, the program will never finish as per the original threading example it's based off.

However, I was under the impression with async/await because of the way the context is saved it would prevent these kinds of issues. Or do all thread safety rules still apply when using async/await?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually a compile optimization issue.  When you compile in release for some reason it predicts complete will never be true and infinitely runs your application.  Since you've based this on another example I'm guessing you already knew that.  But as far as the async / await it can't be blamed.

To make this work you would still need to set complete as a volatile variable like so:

```
        static volatile bool complete = false;
```

This will tell the compiler to check it every cycle regardless and it will work.

I'm not saying I agree with it but what's happening is the compiler is seeing complete unchanged all the way up to the point of the while(!complete) section and since there is no volatile keyword it decides it's never going to change to optimize performance.

Another way to make this work is to remove the compiler optimizations.  You can click on the project Properties and then the Build tab and uncheck 'Optimize code'.  Then it will work in release.

Comment: While this will indeed fix the issue, [Eric Lippert himself discourages the use of volatile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/)

Comment: Ok, as skilled as Eric Lippert is in the summary he is definitely on more of a rant than anything and using it to force an opinion that is definitely wrong.  In C# the bool (Boolean) field is atomic, meaning it is always thread safe.  There is absolutely no reason to put a lock around a Boolean as this will cause a performance degrade.  Don't believe me, try testing it because I have.  Seeing that bool is atomic and always thread safe we can use it for such things multi-threaded.  However; to prevent the compiler from optimizing the variable we add volatile.  I simply disagree with Eric.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much, thought there might have been a bit more to the saved context when using async/await

Comment: However, you can use Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse to accomplish the same thing (signal when finished) that doesn't require the use of volatile.

Comment: @Nabren volatile is just a keyword to remove compiler assumptions from the variable; so that it works as intended.  Monitor.Wait... still introduces a lock and degrades performance.  Try working it out on a console app and test the timing on a loop.  Volatile has zero effect on performance.

Comment: I really appreciated your help on a recent question of mine, so I went looking through your other answers.  I have been trying to develop my command of multi-threading issues, and I found this answer, and your comment to be very helpful.  Thanks.  (PS:  I also really appreciated your comments in your SO profile).

Comment: @AgapwIesu  Thanks.  That's awesome man and I really appreciate you.

Comment: The introductory comment is not true. Compiler does not do such optimization (you can check with disasm), what happens here is one thread does not see another thread change. For example you can add `await` inside the the `while` and the data will be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that access to the `complete` variable is not synchronized. `await` will insert barriers before and after the task runs, to make sure that the task continuation sees new values, but notice that in this example that won't help. After `complete = true`, the fact that the task is awaited does not insert a barrier, and anyway, the looping thread is not synchronizing on the variable read either.

The compiler is allowed to optimize the code, but, even if not, the code might also run forever in practice, as the value of the `complete` variable is never explicitly made visible between the two threads.

This can be solved by synchronizing methods, like 'volatile'.